# Intuition as long term rational thinking

Tags: psychology, rationality

I read this article about [intuition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuition_%28psychology%29) (gut feeling?) on wikipedia, and I simply can't get my head over it. Why is intuition considered as "acquiring knowledge without interference or the use of reason".

Without knowing about some kind of subject you wouldn't have "gut feeling" in a first place.

Another question comes in my mind: Why rational thinking can not be referenced as long term intuition?

Ex: I am finishing high school and I am deciding what to do next: go to work, go to collage/uni, do nothing.

Doesn't my decision come from intuition in a first place? (My decision can be "changed" via rational thinking but again what triggered "thinking about changing my decision"? (intuition?)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read this article about intuition (gut feeling?) on wikipedia, and I
>   simply can't get my head over it. Why is intuition considered as
>   "acquiring knowledge without interference or the use of reason".

Intuition is what we know subconsciously, at the back of our minds

Consciously we use what we can see, hear, taste, touch, smell, but intuition requires higher level of consciousness, i.e. 6th sense.

> Without knowing about some kind of subject you wouldn't have "gut
>   feeling" in a first place.

But perhaps, you do know the answer. The Universe around us is very complex, and our minds are fantastic machines that can take this all in. However, we can only process so much consciously.

> Another question comes in my mind: Why rational thinking can not be
>   referenced as long term intuition?

When someone is trying to solve a problem, they say they will "meditate on this", because meditation allows a person to go to a higher level of consciousness, where they can perceive and understand things they cannot otherwise do with "rational thinking", i.e. seeing hearing, tasting, touching, or smelling.

> Ex: I am finishing high school and I am deciding what to do next: go
>   to work, go to collage/uni, do nothing.
>
> Doesn't my decision come from intuition in a first place? (My decision
>   can be "changed" via rational thinking but again what triggered
>   "thinking about changing my decision"? (intuition?)).

Of course, your decision can be "changed" by rational thinking, but how will you feel if you are going against your intuition?

If your intuition tells you to go to college/university, but your rational thinking tells you to go to work (perhaps because of your current financial situation), will you feel happy, or will you get a sick feeling in your stomach. Perhaps your intuition is telling you that going for higher education is a permanent solution for any financial troubles because you will learn the skills you need for a decent-paying job.